# How do we know that the Uncertainty Principle is valid for macroscopic objects, since we can't prove that empirically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The statement "The HUP is valid for macroscopic objects" can't be confirmed experimentally.

Is the statement just a mainstream-science conjecture?

One can hold that the nowadays instruments are not sophisticated enough to detect the HUP for macroscopic objects. Of course, that is a valid logical possibility.

However, the HUP may be not valid for macroscopic objects. That is another valid logical possibility...

IN SUMMA: we can't resolve the question experimentally (at least nowaday). So, how actually can we have a scientific answer nowaday?

Comment: And some amazingly complicated epicycle which has coincidentally mimicked the orbits predicted by general relativity so far is a logical possibility as well.

Comment: My question is rather about... how we decide between "HUP is valid at microscopic level" and "HUP is not valid for microscopic objects"? Since we cannot solve the question experimentally...

Comment: Why would we care? Physics is not math: it's founded on reality.

Comment: It is logically possible that there are dinosaurs living on Pluto. Nevertheless, I don't believe that the question "How do we know there are not dinosaurs living on Pluto?" would be on topic here.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you asked that question several times already, which were closed. Please do not ask the same question again, but try to edit one question such that it is on-topic here. Then try to re-open.

Comment: The question here, as I already pointed out, is rather about... Why do, lets say, you believe that the HUP is valid at macroscopic level. Unless QT is your religion. So, you can be on-topic, if you elaborate your belief. Since hardly you have any empirical proof for the logical possibility that "the HUP is valid for macroscopic objects".

Comment: Jason, I am afraid you are mistaken. You refer to different questions of mine. If you carefully look at the essence of my questions.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker the questions are essentially duplicates.  The previous version should have been edited to clarify or sharpen the question.

Comment: The [Weber bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_bar) of the LIGO detector for gravitational waves [do very much obey the UP](https://www.ligo.org/science/Publication-SqueezedVacuum/index.php), and all measurements and calibrations are consistent with it. I don't believe you've seriously read up on it, and I imagine you are thinking about wispy theoretical issues, instead...

Answer (score 1):

> The statement "The HUP is valid for macroscopic objects" can't be confirmed experimentally.

Well, it depends on your cutoff for "macroscopic". To my knowledge the [largest such measurement](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6334?context=physics) is $\approx 0.5 \mathrm{\ mm}$ which may already classify as "macroscopic". It is at least visible to the human eye without a microscope.

However, that is rather besides the point of your question as there is always some scale that you can say that HUP hasn't been tested at which you make your cutoff. So, the more important fact is not that there is some maximum size at which it has been experimentally confirmed. The important fact is that it has not been experimentally rejected at any size.

The goal of science is to build models that accurately predict the results of future experimental data, and the most predictive models are the ones that explain the data with the fewest free parameters. Adding a "macroscopic/microscopic cutoff" free parameter would reduce the predictive power of the model without improving the fit in any regime. Heuristically this is known as Occham's razor and quantitatively it is a feature of Bayesian inference.

To understand this, let's make a pair of "toy models". Suppose that we have a binary response variable, $y$ where $y=1$ means that the HUP is verified and $y=0$ means that the HUP is falsified. Suppose that we have a continuous predictor variable, $x$ which is the size of an object in $\mathrm{nm}$. Now, model A is that there is no threshold, so $y(x)=1$ for all $x$. In contrast, model B is that there is a threshold, so $y(x) = \mathrm{bool}(x<x_0)$ where $x_0$ is the threshold, a free parameter to be determined by experiment.

Now, suppose for simplicity that before collecting the data we believe that $x_0$ is somewhere between 0 and 1000000 with all values in that range equally likely (remember $x$ is the size in $\mathrm{nm}$). So, we run an experiment at the atomic scale and find $y(0.1)=1$. Now, we want to see how well the two models stack up against this experiment.

The probability of the observation $y(0.1)$ given model A is $P(y=1|A)=1.0$, but for model B we have to marginalize over all of the possible values of $x_0$ for $0.1<x_0<1000000$ B is confirmed, but for $0<x<0.1$ B is falsified. So when we marginalize over all possible $x_0$, we get $P(y(0.1)=1|B)=0.9999999$. In other words, the more flexible model is *slightly* less predictive than the model with fewer free parameters.

This difference is very slight for $x=0.1$, but what about for $x=500000$? For that A is again confirmed $P(y=1|A)=1.0$ but B is only confirmed for $500000 < x_0 < 1000000$ and B is falsified for $0<x_0<500000$ so $P(y(500000)=1|B)=0.5$. So for that experiment, the evidence is twice as strong for model A than it is for model B. If we use both A and B to predict experiments then the data will be better predicted by model A than model B.

As we accumulate more and more $y(x)=1$ data over a broader range of $x$, the support for A grows. There is no explanatory benefit for the more complicated model with a free parameter. Even though the evidence is consistent with both models, the evidence actually favors the simpler model over the more complicated one.

> However, the HUP may be not valid for macroscopic objects. That is another valid logical possibility.

It is a valid logical possibility. There are **always** an infinite number of other valid logical possibilities to explain any given data set. Merely being a valid logical possibility is a very low bar to clear. After all, this is science, not just mathematics.

The question is how well do such models predict the data? Currently they predict it worse than the usual model. Therefore, the current best model is that there is no such cutoff. This is the model which accurately explains the existing data and gives the tightest predictions for unmeasured data.

Comment: "It also cannot be rejected experimentally." So, the statement is unfalsifiable.

Comment: "After all, this is science, not just mathematics." That's my point. So, where is the empirical confirmation?

Comment: "Adding a "macroscopic/microscopic cutoff" free parameter would reduce the predictive power of the model without improving the fit in any regime."    Actually, what is added is the assumption that there is not such cutoff. Also, it is not clear at all how that "improves" the predictive power of the model. Since, as we all agree, it can't be confirmed empirically.

Comment: @PavelBorisov I will add a section explaining how a model with no cutoff has higher predictive power than a model with a cutoff. For the rest of your comments, please recall that comments are not for discussion

Comment: Thank you. Please, inform mr where I should check out for your section. I will be glad to read it.

Comment: @PavelBorisov done. See the revised answer

Comment: I am sorry, but your argumentation is fundamentally flawed. To begin with: it's not clear to me what an experiment to falsify HUP at a certain (macroscopic) scale would even look like. "The important fact, it has not been experimentally rejected at any size" is just a play with the burden of proof. The rest of your argumentative elaboration, even if MATHEMATICALLY correct, is just a mathematical special pleading (ad hoc construction).

Comment: @PavelBorisov again, comments are not for discussion. If you would like a discussion rather than a Q&A then you need to go to a discussion forum not a Q&A forum. Perhaps try physicsforums.com where I am also active. Your comment is completely incorrect (the argumentation is sound, there are clear experiments that could falsify HUP, the burden of proof is on the more complicated model, and Bayesian inference is principled not ad hoc), but this is not the place for a discussion. I would be glad to have such a discussion in the appropriate place